# What is the approach for edge_ngram search query to have a correct word slop count?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to make a search-as-you-type search with some fuzziness within n fields. Also, the distance between tokens is a must, so I've decided to use `edge_ngrams` with a bool query. But as far the tokens are edge_ngrams the slop is calculated in the same way - by ngrams instead of words.

Initial conditions:

Index settings PUT http://localhost:9200/test

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "someField": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
      },
      "anotherField": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": "1",
    "number_of_replicas": "1",
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample document POST http://localhost:9200/test/_create/1

```json
{
  "someField": "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven",
  "anotherField": "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven"
}
```

Search request POST http://localhost:9200/test/_search?typed_keys=true

```json
{
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "someField": {},
      "anotherField": {}
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "dis_max": {
          "tie_breaker": 0.9,
          "queries": [
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "someField": {
                  "query": "thre elev",
                  "slop": 24
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "anotherField": {
                  "query": "thre elev",
                  "slop": 24
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        //  my custom filters...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to see the example document searching for "thre elev" - this works fine.

But the problem is that there are 7 words between `three` and `eleven`, but the `edge_ngram` tokenization affects it, so the real slop is higher & unpredictable. So if I use slop of 24 then it works, but that's not norma, I guess...

Is there any way to tune the `match_phrase` search to avoid this?

I don't have enough ES expertise to define the alternative wayout for this type of search, but maybe could anyone suggest another approach for this?

Comment: Hi, why do you want to use `slop`?

Comment: `GET test/_analyze
{"text":["one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven"],"analyzer":"autocomplete"}`
To understand "how Elasticsearch analyze the text" use the above API

Comment: There are more than 7 words between three and eleven for **someField** because the keywords in that field are parsed. But you can use **anotherField** and the slop will be 7.

Comment: @MusabDogan I need to use slop to ensure that the words from the phrase, that I'm searching for, are located nearby or on a certain distance that is not greater than `n`.

Comment: The `anotherField` has default analyzer, so I won't have any single match for the `"query": "thre elev"`. Making it's analyzer `autocomplete` will result in the same slop problem, because it's just a text field with word tokens...